# Creating a Field in Table that calculates days from a certain date already entered Access QUERY

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using Access Database

I have a table called "Pasture Management" and i am trying to calculate and add a "Days Empty" column to the table. I already have a date column called "Actual Move out Date" and i want to know how many days the paddock has been empty since that move out date. I know that i need to use the DateDiff Code in a query using SQL, but not to sure how to write it correctly so that it calculates the days empty and adds that value into the table under the "Days Empty" Column.

So if i have a Move out Date for stock in a paddock of 15/6/2021, i want Access to be able to calculate the number of days the paddock has been empty for when i run the report and then add this number into the "Days Empty" column in my "Pasture Management" Table.

Comment: Sample data would greatly help your question here.

Comment: You should add sample data and the expected result.

Comment: days empty = DATEDIFF ( day, date empty, actual move out day)

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. E.g. DATEDIFF is a product specific function - and should not be recommended as long as the dbms is unkown.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Comment: Also, tables have _columns_, not fields. (But a date has a year field, a month field and a day field...)

Comment: Edited Question with an example of what i would like.

Comment: Thankyou all. I have worked in out by putting in the field column of my query with the datediff function